# Qt static build 5.15.2 x86 on Windows, build errors

Tags: windows, build, static, qt5, mingw

I'm trying to build a static Qt 5.15.2, 32bit on Windows 10.
I have a full instalation of Qt package and I'm trying to use the tools directly from this instalation to have all tools in proper version + I have a Python 2.7 and Strawberry Perl in latest version.

My steps:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/qt/qt5.git --branch 5.15.2

SET _ROOT=C:\Qt\git\qt5
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtbase\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_32\bin;%PATH% 
SET PATH=%_ROOT%\qtrepotools\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL-Win32\bin;%PATH%
SET _ROOT=

configure.bat -release -static -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++ -prefix "C:\Qt\5.15.2_static" -skip webengine -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples

mingw32-make
```

At first I tried x64, not working so then x32.. not working. Several different configurations.
Overall it seems good for first hours and then I get many errors. But it is always the same type of errors.

I tried to disable some packages like QtContacts or QtPim but the same type of errors just apperas somewhere else. Found something on Google about compiler version maybe but I'm using the one provided by Qt instalation package.

Error log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YOVCT9yg7Ufq0Z6DWSdPcU_lSWtyu6od/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have no experience with building Qt with `configure.bat`, but I have been able to build Qt 5.15.2 with MinGW+w64, both static and shared, using `./configure` in MSYS2 shell (https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: Something like this for static build: `./configure -platform win32-g++ -opensource -confirm-license -release -static -no-pch -no-rpath -strip -skip "qtserialbus" -qpa windows -gif -sql-odbc -sql-sqlite -opengl desktop -icu -system-pcre -dbus-linked -system-sqlite -system-zlib -system-libpng -system-libjpeg -system-doubleconversion -system-freetype -system-harfbuzz -libproxy -system-proxies -no-libudev -openssl-linked -no-xcb -no-compile-examples -skip qtwebengine -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtlocation -nomake examples -plugin-manifests -pkg-config`